# How make can restore state after failure

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Considering the following:

```
all:
    mv info.h info.h.back
    generate_info.sh
    compile
    mv info.h.back info.h
```

How do I force make to run the last line even if compilation failed?

I am aware of `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` but this deals only with removing targets on failure.

I am also aware of the option to add `-` before the compile command. Unfortunately this will make the whole make to return with a good error code, which is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force make to do this.  You'll have to arrange for it to be done in your shell script, yourself.  Make will send every "logical line" of the shell script to the same shell command.  Turn multiple physical lines into one logical line by appending backslashes to the end of the physical lines.

So, for example:

```
all:
    mv info.h info.h.back
    generate_info.sh && compile; \
    r=$$?; mv info.h.back info.h; \
    exit $$r
```

This saves the return code of the two commands in the shell variable `r`, then runs the `mv` command, then exits the shell with the result code that was saved.

The `generate_info.sh && compile` means that the second command (`compile`) will only run if the first command (`generate_info.sh`) succeeds.